# Changing the order of a flex-container's child elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I have a navigation menu and some sections. Whenever a specific section is scrolled to, the corresponding navigation element is given the `.active`-class through a jQuery function I've made.

What I also want to do is "push" the active child-element of the navigation menu to the front of the menu, while "pushing" the last active element to the back of the menu. See pictures below for clarification:

### **What I have right now**

[image]

### **What I want**

As you can see, the `item 2`-element is the first element of the menu, while the `item 1`-element is the last element of the menu.

[image]

### **What I've tried**

The `container`-element has the `display: flex;`-property, so naturally I tried using the `order`-properties on the different navigation elements in my function, but haven't had any success with it.
If anyone has some tips on how to achieve this, I would be grateful as I quite frankly have no idea where to start.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/sigurdmazanti/pen/xxpBxNR

**Snippet:**

```js
var nav = $(".container");
var sections = $(".section");

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top,
      bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find(".nav").removeClass("active");
      nav.find("." + $(this)[0].id).addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  position: sticky;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
}

.container .nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.section {
  height: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.section.one {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.section.two {
  background-color: red;
}

.section.three {
  background-color: green;
}

.section.four {
  background-color: blue;
}

.section.five {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav one">item 1</div>
  <div class="nav two">item 2</div>
  <div class="nav three">item 3</div>
  <div class="nav four">item 4</div>
  <div class="nav five">item 5</div>
</div>

<div class="section one" id="one">item 1</div>
<div class="section two" id="two">item 2</div>
<div class="section three" id="three">item 3</div>
<div class="section four" id="four">item 4</div>
<div class="section five" id="five">item 5</div>
```

Comment: You can use order to sort i guess.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work nicely for you:

```css
.container > .nav.active {
  order: -1;
}
```

See it working here:

```js
var nav = $(".container");
var sections = $(".section");

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top,
      bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find(".nav").removeClass("active");
      nav.find("." + $(this)[0].id).addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  position: sticky;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
}

.container .nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.section {
  height: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.section.one {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.section.two {
  background-color: red;
}

.section.three {
  background-color: green;
}

.section.four {
  background-color: blue;
}

.section.five {
  background-color: purple;
}

.container > .nav.active {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav one">item 1</div>
  <div class="nav two">item 2</div>
  <div class="nav three">item 3</div>
  <div class="nav four">item 4</div>
  <div class="nav five">item 5</div>
</div>

<div class="section one" id="one">item 1</div>
<div class="section two" id="two">item 2</div>
<div class="section three" id="three">item 3</div>
<div class="section four" id="four">item 4</div>
<div class="section five" id="five">item 5</div>
```

Comment: Great hack! Thank you! Have you used this before and perhaps have an animation as well?

Comment: @SigurdMazanti No problem. I have used this before but it was a slightly different application. Worked great! An animation would definitely juice it up.

Answer (score 0):

On the phone now so hard to edit, but look at the ordering in css . Just change the order style in your script.

Its unclear if you want this to animate though.. a common trick is to copy thw full row and place it afterwards in a div with no overflow. Then on scrolling to the  previous or next would quickly rest the bar to mimic endless scrolling..

```js
var nav = $(".container");
var sections = $(".section");

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top,
      bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find(".nav").removeClass("active");
      nav.find("." + $(this)[0].id).addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  position: sticky;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
}

.container .nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.section {
  height: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.section.one {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.section.two {
  background-color: red;
}

.section.three {
  background-color: green;
}

.section.four {
  background-color: blue;
}

.section.five {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div style="order:3" class="nav one">item 1</div>
  <div class="nav two">item 2</div>
  <div style="order:1" class="nav three">item 3</div>
  <div class="nav four">item 4</div>
  <div class="nav five">item 5</div>
</div>

<div class="section one" id="one">item 1</div>
<div class="section two" id="two">item 2</div>
<div class="section three" id="three">item 3</div>
<div class="section four" id="four">item 4</div>
<div class="section five" id="five">item 5</div>
```

Comment: An animation would be great. Your solution covers pretty much what I already tried though... and also, I do think having 5+ navigation menus for this is a bit overkill.

Comment: Well i basicly says the same as the excepted answer, so?..but using order will not let you animate it.